# how can I get indicator-synapse working?

Tags: applications

I've installed (sudo apt-get install indicator-synapse), and I see the icon on the wingpanel.  However, I can't activate it with any shortcut (ctrl-space doesn't work, which I though was the default), and can't find the entry in dconf-editor (net/launchpad/indicator-synapse) to change the shortcut!

Comment: The standard response first: Have you logged out and in yet? Have you restarted your machine?

Comment: Did you tried alt+f2 and than type `indicator-synapse`?

Answer (score 3):

After installing synapse you should either restart wingpanel or log out and back in.

To restart wingpanel: `killall wingpanel`

The default indicator-synapse shortcut is: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Details here:

[install indicator synapse](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/synapse-indicator-new-search.html)

[Configure synapse](http://synapse.zeitgeist-project.com/wiki/index.php?title=Plugins/Configuration)

Comment: thanks, Alt + Super + Space works.  however, the config file the link indicates seems to be for synapse rather than indicator-synapse :/

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me originally posted by Karut on Launchpad:

Manually installing a newer (sucessfully built) build of synapse (529) actually solves this problem. Once you update synapse via package manager the problem of course will reappear.

Download it here.

https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/unstable-upstream/+sourcepub/4275868/+listing-archive-extra

or alternatively:
https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+recipe/indicator-synapse-daily

Jay

Comment: same problem: it installs fine and I can use it with super + alt + space, but still can't find where to change the hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around for this, using xdotool. This tool lets you simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.

Here, we are going to find the coordinates of the mouse, and emulate a mouse click on the synapse indicator using a command and set a shortcut key for the command.

**Step 1: Install xdotool.**

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

**Step 2: Move your mouse over the synapse icon and get mouse location**

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

You should get output like this:

```
x:1105 y:14 screen:0 window:39845936
```

**Step 3: Add keyboard shortcut for indicator**

Go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts.`

Click the + and enter the below command:

```
xdotool mousemove x y click 1 mousemove restore
```

Replace `x` and `y` with the values you got. Set the shortcut as `Ctrl + Space` Logout and Login again.

Voilà!

Comment: neat.  will try this out - do you know how well it would work changing monitor configurations? I do that fairly often.

Comment: You'll have to change it every time. Another problem with this method is, if more icons (like when Skype is launched) occur, the setting won't work. I'm looking for a way to set a fixed position for the icons.